# laravel FatalThrowableError "calss not found"

Tags: php, laravel

I am new with laravel and I add "steffenbrand/dmn-decision-tables" package then I created the function to use it
like this step [steffenbrandDmn](https://github.com/steffenbrand/dmn-decision-tables)
but when I use the function don't work and throw an exception
**Class 'App\Http\Controllers\HitPolicy' not found**
***canyoneone help me???***

Comment: use this calss:
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use SteffenBrand\DmnDecisionTables\DecisionTableBuilder;
use SteffenBrand\DmnDecisionTables\DecisionTableBuilderInterface;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created a policy and you are using it within your controller, but haven't imported.

So in your controller class, above the class declaration put:

```
use App\Policies\HitPolicy;
```

or the path to the `HitPolicy` class wherever is created.